# How to expose a Minkube IP to the Host IP (Kubernetes/k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

How can I expose a Minikube Service IP to Host IP address?

Example: Minikube Service IP  192.168.49.2
[image]
Example: Minikube Pod IP 10.99.14.89
[image]
Example: Host IP 192.168.21.79
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to conquer this issue. (1:expose Service 2:Expose pod)

Example 1: expose Service
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/app 8881:8888

[image]
[image]

Reference: [Forward a local port to a port on the Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod)

Comment: I am using kubernetes in docker desktop. While I issue this type of command sevice/app then the cmd gets timeout. But works fine with pod directly. Do you have any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: @AmimulEhsanRahi please check your pod name and replace it, "app" is my pod name.